# neomutt oauth stopped working

Tags: mutt, neomutt, oauth2

Since last week oauth2 just stopped working. It did a while before and healed itself mysteriously and I am eager to find out what is happening here. I installed thunderbird for reference and it is working — receiving and sending emails is possible with oauth2.

I have an MS Office account and configured the authentication making use of [mutt_oauth2.py](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/blob/main/contrib/oauth2/mutt_oauth2.py) script linked in the [docs](https://neomutt.org/guide/optionalfeatures.html#6-%C2%A0oauthbearer-and-xoauth2-support) following the steps outlined in the [README](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/blob/main/contrib/oauth2/mutt_oauth2.py.README#L185).

Running the script manually yields a token. Testing suggests, imap and smtp communication is basically working (the [script](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/blob/main/contrib/oauth2/mutt_oauth2.py#L398) seems to log in successfully if I am correct).

```bash
/home/me/bin/mutt_oauth2.py /home/me/.neomutt/token --provider microsoft --verbose --test
[…]
IMAP authentication succeeded
POP authentication succeeded
SMTP authentication succeeded
```

And neomutt was working as well – however stopped to do so a few days ago. Logs tell

```
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> mutt_socket_write_d() 4> c0000 CAPABILITY
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> mutt_socket_readln_d() 4< * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<3> cmd_parse_capability() Handling CAPABILITY
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<3> cmd_parse_capability()  Found capability "IMAP4": 0
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<3> cmd_parse_capability()  Found capability "IMAP4rev1": 1
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<3> cmd_parse_capability()  Found capability "AUTH=XOAUTH2": 9
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<3> cmd_parse_capability()  Found capability "SASL-IR": 13
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<3> cmd_parse_capability()  Found capability "IDLE": 12
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<3> cmd_parse_capability()  Found capability "NAMESPACE": 4
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> mutt_socket_readln_d() 4< c0000 OK CAPABILITY completed.
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<3> imap_cmd_step() IMAP queue drained
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> imap_authenticate() Trying user-defined imap_authenticators
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> imap_authenticate() Trying method oauthbearer
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> mutt_sasl_client_new() SASL local ip: 2001:db8::1;38986, remote ip:2001:db8::2;993
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> mutt_sasl_client_new() External SSF: 256
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> mutt_sasl_cb_log() SASL: No worthy mechs found
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> imap_auth_sasl() oauthbearer unavailable
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> imap_authenticate() Trying method xoauth2
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<M> imap_auth_oauth_xoauth2() Authenticating (XOAUTH2)...
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> msgwin_recalc() recalc done, request WA_REPAINT
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> msgwin_repaint() repaint done
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> ibar_recalc() recalc done, request WA_REPAINT
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> helpbar_repaint() repaint done
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> menu_repaint() repaint done
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> ibar_repaint() repaint done
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<E> mutt_account_getoauthbearer() OAUTH token is too big: 2304
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> msgwin_recalc() recalc done, request WA_REPAINT
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<5> msgwin_repaint() repaint done
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> mutt_sasl_client_new() SASL local ip: 2001:db8::1;38986, remote ip:2001:db8::2;993
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> mutt_sasl_client_new() External SSF: 256
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> mutt_sasl_client_new() External authentication name: karl.liebich@ida.me
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> mutt_sasl_cb_authname() getting authname for outlook.office365.com:993
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<2> imap_auth_sasl() xoauth2 unavailable
[2023-06-18 10:35:17]<E> imap_authenticate() No authenticators available or wrong credentials
```

- `libsasl2` related packages have last been updated in March so there was no change.
- Neither was in my neomutt configuration or password.
- The  `OAUTH token is too big: 2304` message is known and did not have any impact in the past.

---

Any hints on how to debug this any further and what to do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an identical setup with `neomutt`, `mutt_oauth2.py` and a Microsoft account. Noticed exactly the same problem today, then upgraded to the newest version of `neomutt` (version 20230517). This resolved the problem.

To upgrade to the latest version, you will likely have to [build `neomutt` from source](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/releases/latest); Unix/Linux distributions tend to package somewhat older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @yb1. For Ubuntu 22.04 the instructions can be found below. I peeked at the installation from the repos to get a hint on which options to set.

I used a docker container to keep my system clean. After downloading the [sources](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/releases/latest) and `cd`-ing into the inflated folder I ran

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/wrk ubuntu

cd /wrk
apt update
apt install build-essential gettext libncursesw5-dev pkg-config libidn2-dev libgpgme-dev libsasl2-dev liblua5.4-dev libnotmuch-dev libsqlite3-dev libgnutls28-dev libtokyocabinet-dev libkrb5-dev

./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr {--includedir=${prefix}/include} {--mandir=${prefix}/share/man} {--infodir=${prefix}/share/info} --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules {--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu} --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --mandir=/usr/share/man --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --with-mailpath=/var/mail --gpgme --lua --notmuch  --gnutls --gss  --mixmaster --sasl --tokyocabinet --sqlite --autocrypt --disable-doc
make
```